# ModelSim Altera 10.1d - verilog I can't get wave forms

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, modelsim, waveform, intel-fpga

I have a basic bistable code, i compile it without any errors, but when i whant to add waveforms after i hit run(f9), my altera program doesn't do anything...
Here is my code:

```
module bistable(input a, 
            input rst, 
            input ck,
            output reg out);
always@(posedge ck) 
if(!rst) out<=0; 
   else out<=a;         
endmodule
```

Test module:

```
module test();
reg a; 
reg ck; 
reg rst; 
wire out; 
bistable bis(.a(a),.ck(ck),.rst(rst),.out(out));

initial begin
ck=0;
forever ck=~ck;
end
initial begin
a=1;
rst=0;
#14 rst=1;
#20 rst=0;
#10;
$stop;
end
endmodule
```

I did programs without clock and my waveforms appeared very well, but that's not what I think is the cause of my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forever ck=~ck;` is a zero time infinite loop. The simulation will not move to the next time step until all operations on the current time step is completed (which is impossible when there is a zero time infinite loop).

Adding time delay to your clock will help. For example: `forever #5 ck=~ck;`

Check your log file. Some simulators will report errors or warnings when they encounter an infinite loop.